# can UIimage have text or string at xcode?

Tags: xcode, uiimage, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I was building an application, an example I have MapView that will show many annView, the question is How can I make it all different, with a little subtitle, such as number or something like symbol

can UIImage do that?

I want to make something like Yelp

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly it sounds like you could get what you want with a custom UIView that contained a UIImageView and a UILabel.

Comment: look at the code at my question, that code will make UIImage from UIView, but that doesn't work, Any wrong?

Comment: That solution won't work for annotationview. annotationview accept UIImage not UIView